# How to get the phone number and SIM card slot for the current device, on the callback of onCallAdded?

Tags: android, phone-call, sim-card, incallservice

### Background

I'm working on an app that implements [**InCallService**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService), so it can handle phone calls

### The problem

On devices with multi-SIM, I need to show information of which SIM and associated phone number is used (of the current device).

Thing is, I can't find where to get this information.

### What I've found

1. Given that I reach a function like [**onCallAdded**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#onCallAdded(android.telecom.Call)), I get an instance of [**Call**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call) class, so I need to associate something I get from there, to a sim slot and phone number.
2. Using `call.getDetails().getHandle()` , I can get a Uri consisting only the phone number of the other person that called (who called the current user, or who the current user has called).
3. I can iterate over all SIM cards, but can't find what I can use to map between them and the current call:

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
for (final SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()) {
    final TelephonyManager subscriptionId = telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId());
}
```

4. There was an old code that doesn't work anymore that uses `call.getDetails().getAccountHandle().getId()` and `SubscriptionManager.from(context)getActiveSubscriptionInfoList().getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` .
5. I think I can use `telephonyManager.getSubscriptionId(callDetails.getAccountHandle())` , but it requires API 30, which is quite new...

### The questions

Given a phone call that I get from this callback (and probably others), how can I get the associated SIM slot and phone number of it?

I prefer to know how to do it for as wide range of Android versions as possible, because InCallService is from API 23... It should be possible before API 30, right?

Comment: Does `TelecomManager.getPhoneAccount()` work?

Comment: @vlp It actually seems to work well ! Sadly I can't test on old devices (don't have any) and the emulator can't have multi-SIM, but it looks promising. I used this to get the phone number: telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(call.details.accountHandle)?.address?.schemeSpecificPart and then I've found it from the list of subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList in the number field. Why didn't you write it in the answers? And how did you find out about it? I tried to search about it for hours...

Comment: To be honest -- I read about it in the official documentation and never tried it. I am glad that it works for you. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @vlp Please write on your answer where you got it from.

Comment: I have this information purely from the official Android documentation.

Comment: @vlp But how did you think about checking TelecomManager ?

Comment: I found it there by chance. Thank you for providing your final code in the answer. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `call.getDetails().getAccountHandle()` to get [PhoneAccountHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/PhoneAccountHandle).

Then use [TelecomManager.getPhoneAccount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#getPhoneAccount(android.telecom.PhoneAccountHandle)) to get [PhoneAccount](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/PhoneAccount) instance.

---

Permission `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS` is needed for applications targeting API level 31+.

---

Disclaimer: I am no Android expert, so please do validate my thoughts.

---

EDIT: So solution for both before API 30 and from API 30 could be as such:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun handleCall(context: Context, call: Call) {
    var foundAndSetSimDetails = false
    val callDetailsAccountHandle = callDetails.accountHandle
    val subscriptionManager = context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
    val telephonyManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val telecomManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
    val hasReadPhoneStatePermission =
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    val phoneAccount = telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(callDetailsAccountHandle)
    //TODO when targeting API 31, we might need to check for a new permission here, of READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
    //find SIM by phone account
    if (!foundAndSetSimDetails && phoneAccount != null && hasReadPhoneStatePermission) {
        val callCapablePhoneAccounts = telecomManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts
        run {
            callCapablePhoneAccounts?.forEachIndexed { index, phoneAccountHandle ->
                if (phoneAccountHandle != callDetailsAccountHandle)
                    return@forEachIndexed
                if (!phoneAccount.hasCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SIM_SUBSCRIPTION))
                    return@run
                //found the sim card index
                simName = phoneAccount.label?.toString().orEmpty()
                simIndex = index + 1
                foundAndSetSimDetails = true
                return@run
            }
        }
    }
    //find SIM by subscription ID
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && hasReadPhoneStatePermission) {
        try {
            val callSubscriptionId: Int =
                telephonyManager.getSubscriptionId(callDetailsAccountHandle!!)
            for (subscriptionInfo: SubscriptionInfo in subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
                val activeSubscriptionId: Int = subscriptionInfo.subscriptionId
                if (activeSubscriptionId == callSubscriptionId) {
                    setSimDetails(telephonyManager, subscriptionInfo)
                    foundAndSetSimDetails = true
                    break
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    //find SIM by phone number
    if (!foundAndSetSimDetails && hasReadPhoneStatePermission) {
        try {
            val simPhoneNumber: String? = phoneAccount?.address?.schemeSpecificPart
            if (!simPhoneNumber.isNullOrBlank()) {
                for (subscriptionInfo in subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
                    if (simPhoneNumber == subscriptionInfo.number) {
                        setSimDetails(telephonyManager, subscriptionInfo)
                        foundAndSetSimDetails = true
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (!foundAndSetSimDetails)
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun setSimDetails(telephonyManager: TelephonyManager, subscriptionInfo: SubscriptionInfo) {
        var foundSimName: String? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            val telephonyManagerForSubscriptionId =
                telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(subscriptionInfo.subscriptionId)
            foundSimName = telephonyManagerForSubscriptionId.simOperatorName
        }
        if (foundSimName.isNullOrBlank())
            foundSimName = subscriptionInfo.carrierName?.toString()
        simName = if (foundSimName.isNullOrBlank())
            ""
        else foundSimName
        simIndex = subscriptionInfo.simSlotIndex + 1
    }
```

Comment: For which function do you see that we need `READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`  permission? Also, would it be required even if I use the relatively new API, of `telephonyManager.getSubscriptionId` , which I them find in the list of `subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList` items, checking their `subscriptionId` ?

Comment: Documentation states that `TelecomManager.getPhoneAccount()` needs `READ_PHONE_NUMBERS` on API level 31+, `TelephonyManager.getSubscriptionId` needs `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` needs `READ_PHONE_STATE` or carrier privileges. Also note that [`SubscriptionInfo.getNumber()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo#getNumber%28%29) you plan to use needs some permissions (`READ_PHONE_STATE` below API level 30 or one of `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`/`READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`/`READ_SMS` on API level 30+) or carrier privs.

Comment: So for the `telephonyManager.getSubscriptionId(callDetails.getAccountHandle())` followed by lookup in `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` approach you would theoretically need `READ_PHONE_STATE` (`TelephonyManager.getSubscriptionId`+`SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()`) and then respective privileges for reading information from `SubsciptionInfo` (`READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`/`READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`/`READ_SMS` to get phone number). Assuming API level 30+. Please cross validate my thoughts.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include full code of both cases. As for permissions, thanks. Both cases require READ_PHONE_STATE when targeting API 30. I think that when targeting API 31, only the `getPhoneAccount` would be problematic, but then it is used only for the case of before API 30, so it should be fine. I tried now and it warned me only about the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, though, so no idea if there are more possible issues in this code. Reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205726880 . If you have any other things that you think are important, please let me know.

Comment: Google answered me about how to do it, but not sure about what they wrote : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204791554#comment5